# purgeIdleCellConnections only on slow connection

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios6, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I'm facing a problem that appears only on slow connection (Gprs).
I'm sending data using NSURLConnection and after getting the response i got :

```
purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn = 0x5e738e0
```

I searched on the internet but couldn't find something to help me.
Any ideas ?

I'm gonna check again my memory management because it seems that it comes from a memory error but how to deal with it is another story.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you figure out this issue?  I am having the same problem now while downloading images.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't find a way to solve it. It's a strange issue on which i haven't work later on

Comment: in my case, it appears also on WiFi connection & I did not use `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest]`. still,there is no answer in anywhere. iOS6 specific.

Comment: This message is also caused by the Facebook Sdk (3.1) when I try to connect my app with it. Again my connection is kind of slow.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same message because sequential call of `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` method.
In my case, first call was executed normally but second one was cause of `purgeIdleCellConnections: found one to purge conn`.
Your code might have same behavior as mine.

Comment: I'll check, and come back when tested. Thanks